# Resharper forward structural navigation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I recall in previous versions of `Resharper` that when you were creating something like properties and fields in a class, that when you finished your declaration and hit `Tab` it would navigate to the end of the line *after* the closing curly brace. For example, if I wanted to declare `public byte[] Data` with an explicit get and set, I would type:

`public byte[] Data {get; set;}`

After I typed the semicolon following `set`, if I hit tab it would automatically navigate (move) the cursor to *after* the closing curly brace.

With the latest version, however, it seems that structural navigation was changed, and it will now simply navigate to the next "element" or "structure" and if there isn't one, it will simply select *all* of the text in the class, as shown in the following gif:

[image]

Is there any way to get the old behavior back, where hitting tab *wouldn't* select all the text in the file as it does in the gif above?

Comment: I know this is not an answer to the actual problem, but you can also use the "prop" live template for declaring properties.